# How to find if the network path is available or not

Tags: vb6

How to find if the directory is available or not?

Using VB 6.0

databasetext = network path available

```
If Len(Dir(databasetext)) = False Then
MsgBox "Database Path Not Available"
End if
```

I am selecting the file from the network path, if the network path is not available, it showing error "bad file name or number"

How to solve this problem?

Need VB 6 code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my stock library. I think I included all the declarations needed.

```
Private Declare Function FindClose Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal hFindFile As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindFirstFile Lib "Kernel32" Alias "FindFirstFileA" (ByVal lpFileName As String, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long

Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260

Private Type FILETIME
   dwLowDateTime As Long
   dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type

Private Type WIN32_FIND_DATA
   dwFileAttributes As Long
   ftCreationTime As FILETIME
   ftLastAccessTime As FILETIME
   ftLastWriteTime As FILETIME
   nFileSizeHigh As Long
   nFileSizeLow As Long
   dwReserved0 As Long
   dwReserved1 As Long
   cFileName As String * MAX_PATH
   cAlternate As String * 14
End Type

Public Function FolderExists(ByVal FolderSpec As String) As Boolean
   Dim rst As Long
   Dim udtW32FindD As WIN32_FIND_DATA
   Dim lngFHandle As Long
   Dim strFolder As String 'set to FolderSpec parameter so I can change it

   strFolder = FolderSpec
   If Right$(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
      strFolder = strFolder & "\"
   End If
   strFolder = strFolder & "*"   'add the wildcard allows finding share roots

   lngFHandle = FindFirstFile(strFolder, udtW32FindD)
   If lngFHandle  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
      Call FindClose(lngFHandle)
      FolderExists = True
   End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [PathIsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773621(VS.85).aspx) from [Shlwapi.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155716(office.10).aspx). Here is some VB6 code:

```
Private Declare Function PathIsDirectory Lib "Shlwapi" _
    Alias "PathIsDirectoryW" (ByVal lpszPath As Long) As Long

Function DirExists(ByVal sDirName As String) As Boolean   
  'NB The shlwapi.dll is built into Windows 2000 and 98 and later:  ' 
  '   it comes withInternet Explorer 4 on NT 4 and 95. '  
  'NB Calling "Wide" (Unicode) version. Always available. '
  DirExists = (PathIsDirectory(StrPtr(Trim$(sDirName))) <> 0)    
End Function
```

EDIT: You can also use FileSystemObject, but I prefer to avoid the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (including FileSystemObject). In my experience it's occasionally broken on user machines, perhaps because their IT department are paranoid about viruses.

Comment: Interesting about the IT sabotage, is that about security or job security? ;)