# How to extract directory from a file path string?

Tags: vb6, path

I want to select a path only from a fully qualified name.

For example, `C:\Newfolder\iTDC.mdb` is shown in in the text box.

But I want to take only `C:\Newfolder`, removing the `iTDC.mdb`.

How can skip the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
Dim sPath As String

sPath = "C:\Newfolder\iTDC.mdb"

sPath = Left(sPath, InStrRev(sPath, "\"))
```

Comment: Be aware that code will raise an error if there is no backslash in the string.

Answer (score 6):

If you add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (using Project->References), then you can use the `FileSystemObject` to do file-related operations. For example:

```
Dim oFSO as New FileSystemObject

strFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
```

The `FileSystemObject` also has other useful methods for composing paths (`BuildPath`) and for testing for the existence of files, folders, etc. (`FileExists`, `FolderExists`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [PathRemoveFileSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748(VS.85).aspx) function, available in every version of Windows from 2000 and 98. Here is a VB6 implementation.

```
Private Declare Function PathRemoveFileSpec Lib "Shlwapi" _
  Alias "PathRemoveFileSpecW" (ByVal szPath As Long) As Long

'Convert input file path to drive & directory only. (Supports UNC too) '    
Function sPathOnly(ByVal sInput As String) As String
  Dim sWorking As String
  sWorking = sInput
  If (PathRemoveFileSpec(StrPtr(sWorking)) <> 0) Then
    'Call succeeded. Trim trailing Null '
    sPathOnly = sTrimNull(sWorking)
  Else
    sPathOnly = sWorking
  End If
End Function

'Trim trailing null characters (e.g. from a string returned from an API call) '
Function sTrimNull(ByVal sIn As String) As String
  Dim iZeroCharacter As Long
  iZeroCharacter = InStr(sIn, Chr$(0))
  If iZeroCharacter > 0 Then
    sTrimNull = Left$(sIn, iZeroCharacter - 1)
  Else
    sTrimNull = sIn
  End If
End Function
```

I prefer to avoid the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (including FileSystemObject). In my experience it's occasionally broken on user machines, perhaps because their IT department are paranoid about viruses. There are [other useful functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155716%28office.10%29.aspx) in shlwapi.dll, e.g. for testing whether [folders exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135614/how-to-find-if-the-network-path-is-available-or-not/1136408#1136408) or [files exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773584(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
' GetFilenameWithoutExtension:  Return filename without extension from complete path
Public Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(path As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    pos = InStrRev(path, "\")
    If pos > 0 Then
        filename = Mid$(path, pos + 1, Len(path))
        GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Left(filename, Len(filename) - Len(Mid$(filename, InStrRev(filename, "."), Len(filename))))
    Else
        GetFilenameWithoutExtension = ""
    End If
End Function

' GetFilenameWithExtension: Return filename with extension from complete path
Public Function GetFilenameWithExtension(path As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStrRev(path, "\")
    If pos > 0 Then
        GetFilenameWithExtension = Mid$(path, pos + 1, Len(path))
    Else
        GetFilenameWithExtension = ""
    End If
End Function


' GetDirectoryFromPathFilename: Return directory path contain filename
Public Function GetDirectoryFromPathFilename(path As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStrRev(path, "\")
    If pos > 0 Then
        GetDirectoryFromPathFilename = Left$(path, pos)
    Else
        GetDirectoryFromPathFilename = ""
    End If
End Function
```