# VB6: easy way to get folder name from filepath

Tags: vb6, filepath

If I have the full path of a file:

```
eg. c:\files\file.txt
```

What would be the easiest way to get the folder of this file:  `eg. c:\files\`   ?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to extract directory from a file path string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1147123/15639)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract directory from a file path string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147123/how-to-extract-directory-from-a-file-path-string)

Comment: Comment duplicate as well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `FileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(strFullFilePath)` e.g.

```
  Dim strFullFilePath As String
  strFullFilePath = "c:\files\file.txt"

  Dim fso
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  MsgBox fso.GetParentFolderName(strFullFilePath)
```

Note this returns `c:\file` rather than `c:\file\`

Comment: I realise this is probably an innocent accident, but you have posted a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1147123/15639) and then quickly answered your own question: and the solution in your answer is similar to [this answer in the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147123/how-to-extract-directory-from-a-file-path-string/1147131#1147131). I'm not accusing you of anything underhand, I'm sure it was accidental (the duplicate question had a terrible title), but we should close this question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `InStrRev` for searching for the `\`, and `Left$` for extracting the path bit:

```
filename = "c:\files\file.txt"
posn = InStrRev(filename, "\")
If posn > 0 Then
    pathstr = Left$(filename, posn)
Else
    pathstr = ""
End If
```

I'd make a function out of it for ease of use:

```
Function pathOfFile(fileName As String) As String
    Dim posn As Integer
    posn = InStrRev(fileName, "\")
    If posn > 0 Then
        pathOfFile = Left$(filename, posn)
    Else
        pathOfFile = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
' GetFilenameWithoutExtension:  Return filename without extension from complete path
Public Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(path As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    pos = InStrRev(path, "\")
    If pos > 0 Then
        filename = Mid$(path, pos + 1, Len(path))
        GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Left(filename, Len(filename) - Len(Mid$(filename, InStrRev(filename, "."), Len(filename))))
    Else
        GetFilenameWithoutExtension = ""
    End If
End Function

' GetFilenameWithExtension: Return filename with extension from complete path
Public Function GetFilenameWithExtension(path As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStrRev(path, "\")
    If pos > 0 Then
        GetFilenameWithExtension = Mid$(path, pos + 1, Len(path))
    Else
        GetFilenameWithExtension = ""
    End If
End Function


' GetDirectoryFromPathFilename: Return directory path contain filename
Public Function GetDirectoryFromPathFilename(path As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStrRev(path, "\")
    If pos > 0 Then
        GetDirectoryFromPathFilename = Left$(path, pos)
    Else
        GetDirectoryFromPathFilename = ""
    End If
End Function
```