# Using Workbooks object with absolute address while the workbook is not opened

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use the `Workbooks` object (for example) as below:

```
Debug.Print Workbooks("C:\temp\file1.xlsm").path
```

while the `file1` workbook is closed.

But I'm encountering a `Subscript out of range` Run-time error.

What is wrong and how can I work with the Workbook object without needing to open the appropriate workbook?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but to work with `Workbook` object and access it's properties and methods you need to open it anyway.

Comment: So, please offer a better suggestion than using `Workbook` object. An alternative object instead of `Workbooks` object for accessing a Workbook  `.Copy`, `.path` and `.FulName` properties and methods quietly

Comment: Don't get what you want. You just want to write `C:\temp\` ? If you know the full name of a file, there a lots of ways to get the folder, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5375236/7599798

Comment: You already have the path. Do you mean to test for its existence? Otherwise, as above, you need to have the object open in order to access its property i.e. path.

Comment: I need have access the `Workbooks` object property and methods, as shown in above comment, for various applications.

Comment: @QHarr, Of course. I have the path. and "test.xlsm" is existed. I need access its `Workbooks` object properties and methods, without open the workbook, quietly.

Comment: According to MSDN the `Workbooks` collection will only allow access to workbooks currently opened in Excel (see the this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-object-excel ). Thus I think there is no way to do what you want in VBA (without actually opening the file in excel).

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display). You still need to **open** it.

Comment: Because of this unfortunate limitation, I'm so sorry.

Comment: It's possible to read/write to an Excel file without opening if you use ADO. See http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm for an example.

Comment: @Socii: That still opens the workbook - you just don't see it. You cannot read a book without opening it, and you cannot read a file without opening it. If  you mean "don't *display* it" - that's a different story.

Comment: I found the solution is in ADO that Socii guide.

Comment: @FunThomas - ADO does not require the workbook to be opened.

Comment: Depends what you define as "open".  It's doesn't show the excel file, it has no GUI, but for sure it opens the file. That's basically how you read/write data from/to a file.

Comment: ADO approach solution for this question is appreciated.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but i do not think that ADO allows the use of the Workbooks object as you stated in your question. there is still no way to do `Debug.Print Workbooks("file1.xlsm").path`

Comment: @jsotola, That's right. Following the above discussion, I came to the conclusion that there is no way to use `Workbooks` object in this matter, so I think at least reaching above methods and properties with alternates, as ADO for `Workbooks.Open` and more...

Comment: Which is major needed, reach the Workbook content without open it. `Workbooks("C:\file1.xlsm").path` is in hand (This was only an example about using `Workbooks` object), when we use the path for calling Workbook.