# Any suggestions of a VB6 Source Code library?

Tags: vb6

I'm looking for a good VB6 source code library (to extend the language) for things like parsing a path into root, directory, filename, extension, does a file exist, etc.

I'm happy to pay for such a resource if it's a good one (ideally with some sort of reviews/feedback).

I've found one already:
[SourcePlus from AxTools](http://www.axtools.com/products-other.php?tab=sourceplus)

Only downside is that all of their source code is in Classes and I have 12 or so different VB6 apps  that all share a lot of common code (.bas modules).  So if I use one of the classes in on of my Common.Bas routines I then need to add the class to 12 different programs that all use that Common.Bas module.

I'd really prefer to have the code in either one big class or a .bas module so I can add it one time to each VB6 app and be done with it.

FYI, I've also used with good success http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/  and of course StackOverflow but I'd be happy to buy something comprehensive and well done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm in favour of buying libraries in general, but you really can do a lot of file related tasks with free code. Karl E Peterson's excellent [VB6 website](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/) has some great objects written entirely in VB6 - I think they're as reliable as most things I've ever bought. You could just put them in a COM DLL if you dislike managing the classes.

- [Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147123/how-to-select-path-only/1152791#1152791) a file path to drive and directory only.
- [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135614/how-to-find-if-the-network-path-is-available-or-not/1136408#1136408) whether a directory exists.
- [Check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773584%28VS.85%29.aspx) whether a file exists.
- [...I could go on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845797/is-using-the-windows-script-host-especially-the-filesystemobject-hereof-a-good-i/2849249#2849249)

Answer (score 0):

Can you build their source as a COM dll and just refer to it from your own projects?

Comment: My goal was to *reduce* programming by using a library <g>.

Seriously, though, if that library of Classes does have enough of what I want then that might be viable. I've played with making a Active X EXE. I'm guessing a COM dll would be an ActiveX dll, right?